# Undefined behaviour reading lines from a file

Tags: c

I'm getting some odd behaviour when I use this function to read in the contents of a file then split it into individual lines using a double pointer. About 1/3 times it will mess up some other memory in my program, causing another string to be printed incorrectly, and very rarely I get a malloc 'incorrect checksum for object' error. I've narrowed it down to this function since I only get this behaviour when I call it.

```
File* openFile(char* fn)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(fn, "rb");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char* contents = malloc(fsize + 1);
    fread(contents, 1, fsize, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    contents[fsize] = 0;

    File* f = malloc(sizeof(File));
    f->len = 0;
    f->rows = NULL;

    int lastNull = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < fsize; i++)
    {
        if(contents[i] == '\n')
        {
            contents[i] = '\0';
            f->rows = realloc(f->rows, f->len + 1);
            f->rows[f->len++] = &contents[lastNull];
            lastNull = i + 1;
        }
    }

    return f;
}
```

The File struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int len;
    char** rows;
} File;
```

I'm not sure what the function is doing wrong.

Comment: `f->rows = realloc(f->rows, f->len + 1);` You know, pointers take more than 1 byte, right?

Comment: Also, check the return value of fopen, malloc and realloc. All of them may fail.

Comment: The choice of typedef name you have chosen for your struct, `File` although legal, is confusing.  in this context, it is too similar to `FILE`.

Comment: @Gerhardh facepalm, yea forgot about that. `(f->len + 1 )*sizeof(File*)` would be correct right? It seems to have fixed the issue

Comment: You are allocating memory for a char pointer

Comment: Yep I miswrote that, thank you.

Comment: That is the correct size but it is wrong type of pointer.

Comment: Can you please describe the purpose for each member in `File`?  i.e. what is the relationship between the two members, and what is the purpose and use for `len`?  Why do you need a pointer to pointer for `rows`?  Also, if you show an example of a typical input file, that would help.  It will show what the shape of the content is and how best to read it.

Comment: You might think about renaming `len` to `rowcount` or similar. Also `lastNull` is a weird name as there is no `NULL` involved but it is index of start of current row.

Comment: @ryyker len is the number of rows in the file, and I use a pointer for rows so I can size it dynamically based on how large the input is. It is for a general text editor so input will be plaintext, of really any length.

Comment: A suggestion:  define your struct as `typedef struct {int len;   char* line;} content_s;`. Then once reading the file to get the number of lines:  `content_s *content = malloc(numLines * sizeof(*content);`, resulting in `content[numLines];`  This construct allows each instance of `content_s` to represent one line of a file, (its length, and its corresponding line buffer).  Even simpler, use the same length for all lines in file (once determining what that is by using an initial file read).  This will simplify coding for both reading and cleaning memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insufficient memory allocation in `realloc(f->rows, f->len + 1)`

Suggested fix

```
// realloc(f->rows, f->len + 1)
f->rows = realloc(f->rows, sizeof *(f->rows) * (f->len + 1));
```

---

For potentially big files

```
typedef struct {
    // int len;
    size_t len;
    char** rows;
} File;
```

---

`if(contents[i] == '\n')` does not capture a final line in the file that does not end in a `'\n'`.

Comment: yep I have that issue around the final line

Answer (score 1):

> *"I'm not sure what the function is doing wrong."*

In the `for` loop, the line:

```
f->rows = realloc(f->rows, f->len + 1);
```

results in a non-fatal run-time error:

> *"NON-FATAL RUN-TIME ERROR:   "so1.c", line 44, col 23, thread id 9804:   Not enough space for casting expression to 'pointer to pointer
> to char'."*

....which for me eventually lead to:

> *"FATAL RUN-TIME ERROR:   "so.c", line 44, col 23, thread id 9804:   Dynamic memory is corrupt."*

If your stated purpose:

> *"to read in the contents of a file then split it into individual lines using a double pointer."*

matches your actual intent, you can do this in with a simpler set of steps.  pseudo code:

- `fopen` to read the file to get count of lines, and longest line. close file.
- allocate memory, eg:  `char **content = malloc(lines * sizeof(*content));` (test results before using.)
- allocate memory for each line:  `for(i=0;i<lines;i++) content[i] = malloc(longestLine +1);` (again, test results of each.)
- `fopen` file for read once more:  `FILE *fp = fopen(filespec, "r");`
- Use `i=0; while(fgets(content[i++], longestLine + 1, fp )){...}`
- `free()` all memory when finished with it.